# Hive cast string to date dd-MM-yyyy

Tags: string, date, casting, hive

How can I cast a string in the format 'dd-MM-yyyy' to a date type also in the format 'dd-MM-yyyy' in Hive?

Something along the lines of:

```
CAST('12-03-2010' as date 'dd-mm-yyyy')
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "date type with specific format". Type DATE is stored as binary, and displayed by default in ISO format; if you want to display it in another format, you must format it explicitly, on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

try:

```
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('12-03-2010' , 'dd-MM-yyyy'))
```

Comment: That's still a *String*, with *TimeStamp* format. To cast it to a *Date* you must wrap it in `cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(STR_DMY, 'dd-MM-yyyy'))) as date)`

Comment: And yes, I wish there was a better way to manipulate dates in Hive  :-/

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, this is quite an old post now, are there new and improved ways to manipluate dates in Hive that you are now aware of?

Comment: @MrMoose, the obvious answer is: RTFM https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, Thanks! That is a good response, and I will take a look. I am new to Hive and was hoping to be spoon fed :) I know that isn't the right expectation though. I thought that I could now do without the cast as the docs seem to suggest that, post 2.1.0 release, return type of to_date is now date...that doesn't seem to be the case with what I have though. So for me, still no better way to manipulate dates given I'm just trying to cast a string with a fixed format to a date.

Comment: painful all these things

Answer (score 57):

If I have understood it correctly, you are trying to convert a String representing a given date, to another type.

**Note:** (As @Samson Scharfrichter has mentioned)

- the default representation of a date is ISO8601
- a date is stored in binary (not as a string)

There are a few ways to do it. And you are close to the solution. I would use the CAST (which converts to a DATE_TYPE):

```
SELECT cast('2018-06-05' as date);
```

> Result: 2018-06-05 DATE_TYPE

or (depending on your pattern)

```
select cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('05-06-2018', 'dd-MM-yyyy'))) as date)
```

> Result: 2018-06-05 DATE_TYPE

And if you decide to convert ISO8601 to a date type:

```
select cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(regexp_replace('2018-06-05T08:02:59Z', 'T',' ')))) as date);
```

> Result: 2018-06-05 DATE_TYPE

Hive has its own functions, I have written some examples for the sake of illustration of these date- and cast- functions:

**Date and timestamp functions examples:**

Convert String/Timestamp/Date **to DATE**

```
SELECT cast(date_format('2018-06-05 15:25:42.23','yyyy-MM-dd') as date); -- 2018-06-05 DATE_TYPE
SELECT cast(date_format(current_date(),'yyyy-MM-dd') as date); -- 2018-06-05 DATE_TYPE
SELECT cast(date_format(current_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd') as date);  -- 2018-06-05 DATE_TYPE
```

Convert String/Timestamp/Date **to BIGINT_TYPE**

```
SELECT to_unix_timestamp('2018/06/05 15:25:42.23','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'); -- 1528205142 BIGINT_TYPE
SELECT to_unix_timestamp(current_date(),'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'); -- 1528205000 BIGINT_TYPE
SELECT to_unix_timestamp(current_timestamp(),'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss'); -- 1528205142 BIGINT_TYPE
```

Convert String/Timestamp/Date **to STRING**

```
SELECT date_format('2018-06-05 15:25:42.23','yyyy-MM-dd'); -- 2018-06-05 STRING_TYPE
SELECT date_format(current_timestamp(),'yyyy-MM-dd'); -- 2018-06-05 STRING_TYPE
SELECT date_format(current_date(),'yyyy-MM-dd'); -- 2018-06-05 STRING_TYPE
```

Convert BIGINT unixtime **to STRING**

```
SELECT to_date(from_unixtime(unixtime,'yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')); -- 2018-06-05 STRING_TYPE
```

Convert String **to BIGINT** unixtime

```
SELECT unix_timestamp('2018-06-05 15:25:42.23','yyyy-MM-dd') as TIMESTAMP; -- 1528149600 BIGINT_TYPE
```

Convert String **to TIMESTAMP**

```
SELECT cast(unix_timestamp('2018-06-05 15:25:42.23','yyyy-MM-dd') as TIMESTAMP); -- 1528149600 TIMESTAMP_TYPE
```

Idempotent (String -> String)

```
SELECT from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('2018/06/05 15:25:42.23','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss')); -- 2018-06-05 15:25:42 STRING_TYPE
```

Idempotent (Date -> Date)

```
SELECT cast(current_date() as date); -- 2018-06-26 DATE_TYPE
```

Current date / timestamp

```
SELECT current_date(); -- 2018-06-26 DATE_TYPE
SELECT current_timestamp(); -- 2018-06-26 14:03:38.285 TIMESTAMP_TYPE
```

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK you must reformat your *String* in ISO format to be able to cast it as a *Date*:

```
cast(concat(substr(STR_DMY,7,4), '-',
            substr(STR_DMY,1,2), '-',
            substr(STR_DMY,4,2)
           )
     as date
     ) as DT
```

To display a *Date* as a *String* with specific format, then it's the other way around, unless you have Hive 1.2+ and can use `date_format()`

=> did you [check the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) by the way?

Answer (score 4):

Let's say you have a column 'birth_day' in your table which is in string format,
you should use the following query to filter using birth_day

```
date_Format(birth_day, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

You can use it in a query in the following way

```
select * from yourtable
where 
date_Format(birth_day, 'yyyy-MM-dd') = '2019-04-16';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert the whole column:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(transaction_date,'yyyyMMdd')) from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way
select cast("07/15/2022" as date format "MM/DD/YYYY") from dual
Below is a link to the wiki
**https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CAST...FORMAT+with+SQL%3A2016+datetime+formats**