# Convert date from string to date type in Hive

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, unix-timestamp, hue

I want to change string which is in format '29-MAR-17' to date type in Hive. The column in question is named "open_time".

I have tried using:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('open_time', 'dd/MM/yyyy')));
```

But it returns NULL. Subsequently, my objectif is to do something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table_hive WHERE open_time BETWEEN '29-MAR-17' AND '28-MAR-17';
```

With strings, it will definitely not work.
Any help please ?

Comment: What format you want to convert to?

Comment: @Bala : A format supported by Hive. My objectif is to do something like this : SELECT * FROM table_hive WHERE open_time BETWEEN '29-MAR-17' AND '28-MAR-17'; With strings, it will definitely not work.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475465/hive-cast-string-to-date-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

`select to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('29-MAR-17','dd-MMM-yy')))`

Returns `2017-03-29`