# Want week number from different columns of Year, Month & Day

Tags: sql, hive

I want week number from different columns of Year, Month & Day in same table of Hive QL.
IF you can give logic on SQL, that's also fine.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: Please provide sample data, the code you are running, and explain what you mean.

Comment: I have three columns in tables that is Year, Month & Day.
Now I want a temp column which will give me week number So, I can do group by using that temp week number coumn.

Comment: Year Month Day 
2020 4 5 
2020 4 7 
2020 5 1 
2020 5 3 
Year Month Day Week
2020 4 5 1
2020 4 7 2
2020 5 1 3
2020 5 3 4

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the date, month and year into a proper date format and apply weekofyear().

```
Select weekofyear(cast(concat(year,"-",month,"-",date) as date)) from tablename.
```

Please note that I have used cast to convert the concatenated string into date.Howver, you might need to use different method based on your date format. Please refer to the below answer on handling string conversion to date formats.

[Hive cast string to date dd-MM-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475465/hive-cast-string-to-date-dd-mm-yyyy/51044323)

Comment: could you please help me with exact query ?

Comment: I'm getting an error- " Invalid table alias or column reference 'date' "

Comment: Not getting any answer