# How to convert date in string format to date format in HiveQL?

Tags: hive

| name | date |
| --- | --- |
| a | 20230712 |
| b | 20230711 |
| c | 20230710 |
| d | 20230709 |

above is the sample table that I have with me

below is the desired table that I have to make

| name | date |
| --- | --- |
| a | 2023-07-12 |
| b | 2023-07-11 |
| c | 2023-07-10 |
| d | 2023-07-09 |

What to do? Someone please help...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hive cast string to date dd-MM-yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32475465/hive-cast-string-to-date-dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: No thats only a single entry but here its multiple rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
SELECT name, unix_timestamp(date, 'yyyyMMdd')
FROM mytable
```